# Which data type is generated by SQL Server database after a query?

Tags: java, sql-server, types, apache-camel

I send an SQL query via apache camel to a database (SQL Server):

```
sql:select *from [myDataTable]?dataSource=someDataBase
```

Then the answer to this query from the database above is sent via apache camel to a method of some class. Like that:

```
public static void someMethod(@Body List< Map< String, Object > queryResultFromMyDataTable>{...}
```

Question: how does the database know which data type it has to produce to put in the method above?

It, obviously, cannot produce `String` because the method expects `List<Map<String, Object>>`?

Comment: I hope you're not passing through a query straight from user input through a web query

Comment: Its a list with a map per line of the recordset. Its in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Apache Camel expert but from what I understand you get your result in kind of standard way. Every row of the `myDataTable` is returned as an element of the returned `List`. Each element contains all values of that row represented as a `Map<String,Object>` where the key of the map is the name of the column and the value of the map is the value retrieved from the DB for the coresponding column.

You can find more in [the documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.8.x/sql-component.html)

> outputType (common)
>
> Make the output of consumer or producer to SelectList as List of Map,
> or SelectOne as single Java object in the following way: a) If the
> query has only single column, then that JDBC Column object is
> returned. (such as SELECT COUNT( ) FROM PROJECT will return a Long
> object. b) If the query has more than one column, then it will return
> a Map of that result. c) If the outputClass is set, then it will
> convert the query result into an Java bean object by calling all the
> setters that match the column names. It will assume your class has a
> default constructor to create instance with. d) If the query resulted
> in more than one rows, it throws an non-unique result exception.
> StreamList streams the result of the query using an Iterator. This can
> be used with the Splitter EIP in streaming mode to process the
> ResultSet in streaming fashion. There are 3 enums and the value can be
> one of: SelectOne, SelectList, StreamList